# Measurability of infimum of measurable functions on a $\sigma$-ring (from Halmos)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal S)$ be a measure space where $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-ring, not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra. Following Halmos (*Measure Theory*), we say that $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is measurable if $[f\ne 0]\cap f^{-1}(M)\in\mathcal S$ for each Borel $M\subset\Bbb R$. Letting $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $X$, we wish to show that $g=\inf f_n$ is measurable on $X$. In the text, it is shown that $g$ being measurable is equivalent to $[g\ne 0]\cap [g<c]$ being measurable for each $c\in\Bbb R$. Now, he says on page 84 that $[g<c]=\cup [f_n<c]$, which is correct, but this does not directly imply that $g$ is measurable (contrary to what the text seems to claim). One must also show that $[g\ne 0]$ is measurable, for then $[g\ne 0]\cap [f_n<c]$ is measurable for each $n$.

The problem is to write $[g\ne 0]$ as a union/intersection of sets we know are measurable. Clearly $[g<0]=\cup[f_n<0]$, but from above we have at best $[g\ge 0]=\cap [f_n>0].$ How do we show that $[g>0]$ is measurable?

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$[g>0]=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty[g\ge k^{-1}],$$
and that 
$$[g\ge k^{-1}]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [f_n\ge k^{-1}]\in\mathcal S$$ as each $[f_n\ge k^{-1}]\in\mathcal S$. To see this, note that $[f_n\ne 0]\cap[f_n\ge k^{-1}]=[f_n\ge k^{-1}]\in\mathcal S$ since each $f_n$ is measurable. Thus $[g>0]\in\mathcal S$ and $[g\ne 0]=[g<0]\cup [g>0]\in\mathcal S$.